# Some errors in 'vendor/composer/autoload_static.php'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

[image]

[image]

It happened suddenly, I never revise this file. 'vendor/composer/autoload_static.php'

But, the web still can run properly, it seems isn't influenced from it.

Oh, My IDE is phpStorm

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PHPStorm, I am checked the file and found error too because 'prefixLengthsPsr4', 'prefixDirsPsr4', 'prefixesPsr0', 'classMap' are private properties in ClassLoader class. But you can ignore that warning because it does not cause some damages in Laravel. CMIIW

Comment: But it make me feel a little uncomfortable...